# Passing single value to params argument in NUnit TestCase

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, parameter-passing

I have the following test:

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ParametersParseException))]
[TestCase("param1")]
[TestCase("param1", "param2")]
[TestCase("param1", "param2", "param3", "optParam4", "optParam5", "some extra parameter")]
public void Parse_InvalidParametersNumber_ThrowsException(params string[] args)
{
    new ParametersParser(args).Parse();
}
```

The first TestCase (obviously) fails with the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException : Object of type 'System.String' 
cannot be converted to type 'System.String[]'.
```

I tried to replace the TestCase definition with this one:

```
[TestCase(new[] { param1 })]
```

but now I get the following compilation error:

> error CS0182: An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

My solution for now is moving the 'one parameter' case to a different test method.

Still, is there a way to get this test to run the same way as the others?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way could be to use [TestCaseSource](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5), and have a method that returns each parameter set, instead of using TestCase.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17949732/835589) in response to the question '[NUnit cannot recognize a TestCase when it contains an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925916/nunit-cannot-recognise-a-testcase-when-it-contains-an-array/17949732#17949732)', the compilation error stems from a [bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-272503), and can be overcome using the syntax for named test cases, as such:

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ParametersParseException))]
[TestCase(new[] { "param1"}, TestName="SingleParam")]
[TestCase(new[] { "param1", "param2"}, TestName="TwoParams")]
[TestCase(new[] { "param1", "param2", "param3", "optParam4", "optParam5"}, "some extra parameter", TestName="SeveralParams")]
public void Parse_InvalidParametersNumber_ThrowsException(params string[] args)
{
    new ParametersParser(args).Parse();
}
```

Comment: You link to a resharper issue, while the problem seems to be in nunit ... in any case, seems like resharper solved the problem

Comment: Doing this with `new[] { ... }` where the array is of strings gives the error CS0182 as referenced by the OP above. Integer types seem to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't recommend this approach,

yet here is one more way to pass a single argument to a `params` array by using a dummy object parameter before the `params` parameter.

See the example below:

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ParametersParseException))]
[TestCase(null, "param1")]
[TestCase(null, "param1", "param2")]
[TestCase(null, "param1", "param2", "param3", "optParam4", "optParam5", "some extra parameter")]
public void Parse_InvalidParametersNumber_ThrowsException(object _, params string[] args)
{
    new ParametersParser(args).Parse();
}
```

PS A better way to accomplish that would be using the [TestCaseSource](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute) attribute.