# NUnit cannot recognise a TestCase when it contains an array

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, testcase

This is quite simple but annoying behaviour I am running into with NUnit:

I have some tests like this:

```
[Test]
[TestCase( 1, 2, "hello" )]
[TestCase( 3, 5, "goodbye" )]
public void MyClass_MyMethod( int a, int b, string c )
{
    Assert.IsTrue( a < b );
}
```

This works fine and in the ReSharper NUnit pane I can see each TestCase getting its own response in the result.

I have a second TestCase that looks like this:

```
[Test]
[TestCase( 1, 2, new long[] { 100, 200 })]
[TestCase( 5, 3, new long[] { 300, 500 })]
public void MyClass_MyOtherMethod( long a, long b, long[] bunchOfNumbers )
{
   Assert.IsTrue( a < b );
}
```

When I run it I see this:

> One or more child tests had errors Exception doesn't have a stacktrace
>
> public void MyClass_MyOtherMethod(5,3,System.Int64[]) failed

The difference being that with my other tests it draws out each TestCase as a separate checkbox on the test list, whereas this one does not get shown and I have no detail until I run it in a debugger as to what went wrong and where. I am a little concerned about how this test will behave on the build machine. Does anyone have any idea what is going on and why?

Comment: Could also be the ReSharper test runner that doesn't support it.

Comment: Good point, will check the NUnit console.

Comment: What versions of NUnit and Resharper do you use? I remember that some problems were fixed in more late versions of one of them.

Comment: By the way, have not you tried to pass this array marked with `params` modifier?

Comment: NUnit 2.6.2 against ReSharper 7.1 - probably I need to raise this with Jetbrains. What does the params modifier do?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Following on from [this bug at JetBrains](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-272503) it looks as though the solution here is to use the `TestName` attribute on your different cases:

```
[Test]
[TestCase( 1, 2, new long[] { 100, 200 }, TestName="Test 1" )]
[TestCase( 5, 3, new long[] { 300, 500 }, TestName="Test 2" )]
public void MyClass_MyOtherMethod( long a, long b, long[] bunchOfNumbers )
{
   Assert.IsTrue( a < b );
}
```

Everything now shows correctly in ReSharper if one of my tests fails.

Comment: It looks like with current versions of NUnit and ReSharper this workaround is no longer required.

Comment: It still doesn't like it if your first parameter is the array.

Comment: But it works if you have more than one array in the parameter list.

Comment: @JacobBrewer: That's because the signature of `TestCase` expect `params object[]` as its first parameter - so passing in an array will lead to nUnit looking for a test method signature where the parameters match the type and length of the array.

Answer (score 18):

For an array that contains strings, use an `object` array with the `TestCase` attributes along with `params`:

```
[Test]
[TestCase(new object[] {"foo", "bar", "baz"})]
[TestCase(new object[] {"300", "500", "700"})]    
public void MyClass_SomeOtherMethod(params string[] bunchOfStrings)
{
    // assert something...
}
```

Comment: This didn't quite work for me, using MSTest with NUnit adapter.
Error message was `Too many arguments provided, provide at most 1 arguments.` and this must have been at test runner level as I couldn't even step into the test. Adding `params` keyword in the test method signature did the trick.

Comment: Thanks @user1007074. Updated the answer with your fix.

Comment: For Rider 2020.3.2, this is the way for a unit test with a single array parameter.

Comment: This doesn't work for .Net 6.0 projects, and/or whatever version of NUnit I'm using. It throws an error: Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.String[]'. Instead of "new object[]", you have to declare it as a string, or just minimize it with "new[]".

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is to use a string for the array:

```
[TestCase( 1, 2, "100, 200")]
[TestCase( 5, 3, "300, 500")]
public void MyClass_MyOtherMethod(long a, long b, string bunchOfNumbersString)
{
    var bunchOfNumbers= bunchOfNumbersString.Split(',')
                                            .Select(long.Parse)
                                            .ToArray();
   ...
}
```

The upside with this approach is that it will render nicly in the testrunner.

Side note: The `[Test]` is not needed when using `[TestCase]` or at least I don't see that it solves a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I came across an issue with this where the order of the arguments mattered. Using Rider 2020.1.4

```
[TestCase(new string[] { "ABC", "DEF" }, false)]
public void SomeTestWithParams(string[] stringArr, bool someBool) {}
```

Gave me an error, but

```
[TestCase(false, new string[] { "ABC", "DEF" })]
public void SomeTestWithParams(bool someBool, string[] stringArr) {}
```

worked just fine

Comment: second one works because in the TestCase function, you can not directly pass array. Either you pass the first arguemnt as int/string/bool and second argument is array is allowed Or you use the 'new object [] inside the testCase function then you are allowed to pass the array directly'

Answer (score 1):

This works in VS 2017 with NUnit 3.11.0

```
[TestCase(new long[] {5, 6, 942135153})]
public void DummyTest(long[] values)
{
    Assert.That(values != null);
}
```